# How to convert a UIPath Workflow into a Activity or create a Custom Activity?

Tags: workflow, nuget-package, uipath, uipath-studio

I have a workflow which have two parameter as input. One is Log File Path and the Other is message in UI Path. I can use this workflow as by 'Invoke Workflow' activity but i want a custom activity where can i directly use the workflow by giving the dependency to the project.

I have seen that we can convert it into a nuget package and use it but not sure how can i do that.

There is not code involved.

I expect the an activity should be coming up in the activity panel instead of using the invoke workflow activity.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using version 2018.3 or later you can create a library project in Studio, where you put your workflow file.

Then you can publish the library to Orchestrator or the file system and through the package manager import it in your project. From then on you can use it as a custom activity.

Library documentation:  https://studio.uipath.com/docs/about-libraries

Comment: Good point - this essentially allows you to turn any workflow into an activity. Thanks for sharing, wasn't aware of that!

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can't convert an existing workflow into a custom activity, but you could save it as a template. Read more about them [here](https://studio.uipath.com/docs/project-templates).</s> Edit: you can using Libraries, see Mad T's answer.

Regarding custom activities, [this page](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/creating-a-custom-activity) contains a step-by-step guide. You will need Visual Studio, the language itself is up to you (I prefer C#, but that's just personal flavor). There is the free [Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt553321/) available that you can use, but check whether the terms apply.

With VS installed, you would go ahead an create a new class library - just follow their guide.